# Powershell GUI Return file path

Tags: powershell, user-interface

```
cls 

function GenerateForm2 {


#region Import the Assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
#endregion

#region Generated Form Objects
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$listView1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#region ImageList for nodes
$global:imageList = new-Object System.Windows.Forms.ImageList
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 32
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 32
$global:imageList.ImageSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$image1 = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("M:\Powershell\ico files\folder.ico")
$image2 = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("M:\Powershell\ico files\file.ico")

$global:imageList.Images.Add("folder",$image1)
$global:imageList.Images.Add("file",$image2)
#endregion

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------
#Provide Custom Code for events specified in PrimalForms.
$button1_OnClick= 
{
    if ($script:previousItem) {
        Refresh-ListView $script:previousItem
    } else {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Nothing to go back")
    }
}

$doubleClick= 
{
    if ($listView1.SelectedItems[0].tag -eq "File") {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You double clicked a file")

    } else {
        Refresh-ListView $listView1.SelectedItems[0].Name
    }
}

$button2_OnClick= 
{
    $form1.Close()
}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
    $listView1.LargeImageList = $imageList
    Refresh-ListView "c:\"
}

$button3_OnClick=
{
    if($listView1.SelectedItems[0].tag -eq "Folder"){
        $path2 = $listView1.SelectedItems[0]
        $form1.Close()
    }
}
$button4_OnClick=
{

    $pathNew = CustomInputBox


            if(Test-Path $pathNew){
                echo("Folder Already Exists")
            }
            else
            {
                New-Item -ItemType Directory -path $pathNew -Force
                echo("Folder created")
            }
             $path2 = $pathNew
             $form1.Close()


}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.Text = "Windows Browser"
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 689
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 499
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size

$button2.TabIndex = 2
$button2.Name = "button2"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$button2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True

$button2.Text = "Close"

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 602
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 459
$button2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$button2.add_Click($button2_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($button2)

$button1.TabIndex = 1
$button1.Name = "button1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$button1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True

$button1.Text = "Back"

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 13
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 459
$button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$button1.add_Click($button1_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($button1)

$button3.TabIndex = 3
$button3.Name = "button3"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$button3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true

$button3.Text = "Choose"

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 200
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 459
$button3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode =0
$button3.add_Click($button3_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($button3)

$button4.TabIndex = 4
$button4.Name = "button4"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$button4.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true

$button4.Text = "Create"

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 400
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 459
$button4.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button4.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$button4.add_Click($button4_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($button4)

$listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = $False
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 664
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 440
$listView1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$listView1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$listView1.Name = "listView1"
$listView1.View = 0
$listView1.TabIndex = 0
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 13
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 13
$listView1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 32
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 32
$listView1.TileSize = $System_Drawing_Size

$listView1.add_DoubleClick($doubleClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($listView1)

#endregion Generated Form Code

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function2


GenerateForm2

Write-Host $path2
```

This will write out ListViewItem: {test}

i need path2 to be the filepath of the folder i choose.

I have written a gui windows explorer rip off so i can search for files and folders.  button3 is choose.  this button should take the value of what is chose and assign it to path2 and then close the gui.  However i am having trouble realizing this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected foldername written if you change your script line

from

```
$path2 = $listView1.SelectedItems[0]
```

to

```
$Script:path2 = $listView1.SelectedItems[0].Name.ToString()
```

Comment: Nice! thanks a lot that did the trick.  do you mind explaining what the $script: before path2 does?

Comment: It sets the variable at the script level. if you don't use it, $path2 disappears as soon as you are out of that function.